# CImg how to draw Polygon from given x,y co-ordinates?

Tags: cimg

I am trying to draw a closed polygon from 5 points , I am trying with the following code :

```
CImg<float> img(800,800,1,3);
float red[] = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
CImg<int> points(5,2);
int thePoints[] = {40,40,40,200,100,180,120,100,100,40};
int *iterator = thePoints;
cimg_forXY(points,x,y)
    points(x,y) = *iterator++;
img.draw_polygon(points,red).display();
```

I have tried to give the points in ccw order , However I am not getting the polygon as expected .[image: Expected]
What i get is like : [image: Found]

What can i do to generate a polygon as i expected ? How to give the points as input ? ccw or cw order or arbitrary order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually incorrectly define the variable `points`. It should be filled like this:

```
cimg_forX(points,i) { points(i,0) = *(iterator++); points(i,1) = *(iterator++); }
```

The points can be specified in either clockwise or counterclockwise order.

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked , but are you sure that the Points can be of any order ? I tried inserting the point (40,40) in the middle , but the polygon is something different . I think the points should follow ccw/cw order .